# How to programatically add component via controller action

Tags: ember.js

I have a scenario where I have list of items and each item has a create button. When I click on create, I wanted a component to be appended to the list item. This component uses model data as parameter and also accesses store from within. To access the store in the component I am using targetObject.store

The component works well if I add it to the template manually like:

```
{{#each}}
   <div> blah blah  {{my-component data=this.something action="doSomething"}} <button {{action 'add' this}}>Add</button></div>
{{/each}}
```

I can probably show/hide the component using a flag, and toggle it when we click on Add button, but I rather do it dynamically if possible.

I did try this but didn't work for me because I couldn't access store :

```
actions: {

    add: function(obj){
        var view = Ember.View.create({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{my-component action="addQuestion"}}')
        });
        view.set('data', obj.get('something'));

        Ember.run(function() {
            //prolly can get parent view rather than document.body
            view.appendTo(document.body);
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this example answers your question:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/axUNIJE/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, that will come handy. But how to I pass parameters to the component?

Comment: You can simply pass a hash of parameters in the create() method of the component (this is possible with any Ember Class). For example the property 'test':

``
    App.TeamEffortComponent.create({
      test: 'test'
    }).appendTo($('#teameffortul'));
                console.log('added team effort!');
            }
        }
    });
``

Comment: Thank you so much, i was caught up in the conventional approach of using component that it blind sighted me. Thanks again.

Comment: The `jsbin` examples have been removed.