# Append ember component to div on event

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I was wondering how, on some kind of event, could you import into the dom say a component. ie if you have a form with an email and password, and validation for the form, how could you into the email div enter an {{error-component message=message}}, where the message would be "Not a valid email", and into the password div (or td) enter the same component, with a different message.

Algorithm for explanation:

onSubmit(){
validateForm:
if email not valid { importComponent('#emailDiv', "Email not valid") }
if password not valid { importComponent('#passDiv', "Password does not have enough characters") }
}

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set properties that tell the template whether to render an error?

In the controller or component:

```
emailErrors: [],

actions: {
  onSubmit: function() {
    if (/* email not valid */) {
      this.get('emailErrors').addObject('Email not valid');
    }
  }
}
```

In the template:

```
{{input value=email}}
{{#each error in emailErrors}}
  {{error}}
{{/each}}
```

This really should be made into components for better encapsulation and less repetition, but you get the idea. Programmatically inserting components isn’t the Ember Way, I think.

Comment: The errors were just an example, I will be needing this in the future. "programmatically" was the key word to google what I wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378889/how-to-programatically-add-component-via-controller-action