# How to programatically add component via controller action in ember 2.x

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am being faced with the same problem on

[How to programatically add component via controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378889/how-to-programatically-add-component-via-controller-action)
However since I am using ember cli, I am unable to do so.
Here is my source code

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions : {
        remove : function(){
            this.remove();
        },
        add : function()
        {
            Ember.AuthorNameComponent.create().appendTo($('#authors'));
        }
    },
});
```

When I try to run this code, I get undefined error. Also name of component is author-name.

Any help, how can I create component via programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the component, then you don't need the Ember Global.

```
import AuthorNameComponent from '../components/author-name-component'
```

Another way is to have an array of items and base the list of AuthorNameComponent from that.

```
{{#each items as |item|}}
    {{author-name name=item.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @jax-I am getting this error
`Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead`. Any idea?

Comment: Can you try `...create().createElement().element.appendTo($('#authors'));` or maybe `...create().createElement().appendTo($('#authors'));`

Comment: TypeError: _phpApiEmberTestComponentsFormAlert.default.create(...).createElement is not a function