# Adding component dynamically in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

using
Ember             : 1.13.11,
Ember Data        : 1.13.8,
ember-cli         : 1.13.12

I want to add a component dynamically to webpage - this webpage is template of another component don't think that it will make any difference-. Here is my code snippet in which I try to add a component named LyricsEditorLine to `<div>` tag, somehow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378889/how-to-programatically-add-component-via-controller-action)

agenda-alpha/components/lyrics-editor.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import LyricsEditorLine  from 'agenda-alpha/components/lyrics-editor-line';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   afterRenderEvent:function(){
      LyricsEditorLine.create().appendTo($("#in"));
 },
init:function(){
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
  this._super();
 }
});
```

agenda-alpha/templates/components/lyrics-editor.hbs

```
<div id='in'> </div>
```

every time this gives me

```
 'Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead'
```

Looked for `ContainerViewhere` found that it is [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html)
Most of the answers that I found are not using ember-cli and being a beginner makes it harder to understand

I want to be able to add components as much as the user needs

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do that without some potentially bad side-effects. Why can't you just use the Handlebars `{{#if}}` helper to dynamically render the component?

Comment: the number of components that are to be added is not defined. it depends on the user's needs

Comment: You can still do that in Handlebars, you just need to use some sort of loop (there's a few ways to do it). In general, nearly everything you can do with jQuery is going to be possible using Handlebars and computed/stored properties.

Comment: Jup 8,9k commits in our project, basically never needed jquery

Comment: @GJK if you mean to tell me that I can add components dynamically as much as I want, please tell me how

Comment: @kristjanreinhold if you know any source that can help me ditch jquery I will  appreciate it very much

Comment: This is all in the Ember guides. [Here's a guide on rendering a list of items](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/). If you find yourself struggling to get by without jQuery, you're probably missing a few key features. I would read the guide all the way through if you can. Template-based rendering is much different than you're used to, but it's much more powerful.

Comment: Are these actually components or just templates, in this case you could use partial in a loop

Comment: @GJK thanks man, I had some wrong beliefs, though the link is to Ember 2.2 guides that I don't use as mentioned in the beginning of the question but it helped

Comment: Sorry about that. I linked to the latest but there's a dropdown in the top-left corner to change the docs version. [Here's the corresponding guide for 1.13](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you probably want the `{{component}}` helper which allows to [dynamically render a component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/components/defining-a-component/#toc_dynamically-rendering-a-component).

```
{{component "componentName" param1=paramValue param2=anotherParamValue}}
```

Which means you can have (made up example)

```
{{component "lyrics-editor-line" line=line}}
```

One the best things is that `componentName` can be a bound property

```
{{component componentName line=line}}
```

And in your controller/component:

```
componentName: Ember.computed('prop1','prop2', function() {
  if (this.get('prop1') === 'A') {
    return 'my-component-a';
  }
  return 'default-component';
}),

line: computed('prop3', function() {
   return this.get('prop2');
})
```

Also, you can have the component helper inside an each loop (example taken from the Ember documentation)

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
  {{!-- either foo-component or bar-component --}}
  {{component post.componentName post=post}}
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Pedro, but what you offer is just a component that already exist in the .hbs file, but I want the user to be able to add as much as he wants or none at all during runtime, like adding items to shopping cart, your answer makes it only one component,and in case of the loop I tried to add components to the model array but it didn't work

Comment: The component needs to exists in your ember application, not in that particular .hbs file.... or it wouldn't be very useful. As long as the component is available in your application, you can use the `component` helper to show that component.

I don't understand what you mean by "adding components to the model array". Components exist only in the template, your model is for your data. You use your data to choose what to render. And use components to render that data.

Comment: yeah you are right, I just had all this component thing all wrong, I thought that I had to create the component in the controller side and then append it to the DOM, not just updating the array that is sent to the {{each}} helper.

Comment: Glad I helped you learn a bit more about ember. It's not easy but it's worth it. Keep going with your ember app.